# How to disable the panel in the angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

There 3 panels in one html,  i want to disable panel-2 panel-3 intially after the click button i want to enable the panel-2 (the button is in the panel-1), same for the panel-3

Comment: SO is not the tutorials website. Just share your tried code and post your queries.

Answer (score -1):

Set a flag in your Angular code:

```
var $scope.panel2 = false;
var $scope.panel3 = false;
```

on your panels:

```
<div ng-show="panel2">content</div>
<div ng-show="panel3">content</div>
```

This will make the panels show if the condition (the variables panel2 and panel3 in this instance) evaluate to true.

Then, the button you use would need to do this:

```
<button ng-click="panel2 = !panel2">Show/hide panel 2</button>
<button ng-click="panel3 = !panel3">Show/hide panel 3</button>
```

This will toggle with flags when the buttons are clicked.

Comment: Thank u ,actually i want to disable all the elements inside the panel.

Comment: it will only hide the panel!!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you mean by disable. Since you weren't happy with @MyCah ng-show you could have a look at ng-if. ng-if will not just hide it but remove and re render the content on the page.

View:

```
<div>
  <p>Panel 1</p>

  <button ng-click="enablePanel2 = !enablePanel2">Enable/disable panel 2</button>
  <button ng-click="enablePanel3 = !enablePanel3">Enable/disable panel 3</button>
</div>

<div ng-if="enablePanel2">
  <p>Panel 2</p>
</div>

<div ng-if="enablePanel3">
  <p>Panel 3</p>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.enablePanel2 = false;
    $scope.enablePanel3 = false;
});
```

Comment: No problem. If it solved your issue please accept answer.